# Doc for customizing node-red instance on bluemix does not work

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I followed the instruction provided in "https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/Node-RED/nodered.html#nodered" to customize my instance of node-red on bluemix.
[image]

However, I got redirected back to bluemix homepage (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/) when I tried to download starter code by clicking the "Download Starter Code" icon.
[image]

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method (1)** 
The starter code of node-red is available in new UI experience. When you are on that page click on "Try the New Bluemix" on top bar. Then click on "Getting overview" tab. Here you can Download the Starter Code.

**Method (2)** 
You can download the starter code for your application here:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/rest/apps/YOUR_APPGUID/starter-download

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the language of your browser is set to a language different from English. If changing the default language of the browser the problem persists you can try the following workaround: create a new Node-RED application and click on "Add Git". This will create a new repository on IBM DevOps Services containing the starter code. You could download the code from there.

Comment: The reason I wanted to try with "Starter Code" is that I need to customize the core of node-red, that cannot be done with checking out code through git repo as the files shown in the screenshot (https://scontent-hkg3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/12973247_10154269632075628_2442788973996550136_o.jpg) is inaccessible.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer with a possible workaround